# DevKit ruby dk.rb init does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devkit

I was trying to install Ruby 2.0.0 (x64) on Windows by following the procedure as in this link:
https://forwardhq.com/support/installing-ruby-windows
which I was directed to. After looking into other sources, I thought this was the easiest one to follow.

I downloaded Ruby Installer and then installed it. But, afterwards, there was no icon on the Desktop  or in the Start menu directing to a Ruby IDE whatsoever.. strange.

So, I installed Ruby 1.9.4, after uninstalling Ruby 2.0.0. Same thing.

I then dowloaded the corresponding DevKit zip-file, as mentioned, all this before extracting it to C:\DevKit.

Then, as the guide says, I tried the following commands, in PowerShell:

```
chdir C:\DevKit
ruby dk.rb init
```

What I got was this:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:172:in `find': unknown encoding name - CP720     (ArgumentError)
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:172:in `initialize'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:231:in `exception'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:231:in `raise'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:231:in `check'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:254:in `OpenKey'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:385:in `open'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:496:in `open'
from dk.rb:118:in `block in scan_for'
from dk.rb:116:in `each'
from dk.rb:116:in `scan_for'
from dk.rb:138:in `block in installed_rubies'
from dk.rb:138:in `collect'
from dk.rb:138:in `installed_rubies'
from dk.rb:146:in `init'
from dk.rb:313:in `run'
from dk.rb:332:in `<main>'
```

As you can see, dear 'answer-er', there is some kind of error, in the first line of this block.

Afterwards, I said to myself "try the next instruction in the guide, maybe it will work":

```
PS C:\DevKit> ruby dk.rb install
```

So, I got this:

```
Error loading 'config.yml'.  Have you run 'ruby dk.rb init' yet?
```

I am new to Ruby, and I tried searching for an answer... I got nothing.

Help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that you have encountered an issue with the encoding. Can you try the following steps?

Change encoding to 1252

```
C:\DevKit> chcp 1252
c:\DevKit> ruby dk.rb init
```

There are quite a few threads on the Rubyinstaller group, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/CE6fuao_ov8) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyinstaller/tu42uWMQKQU/n3Nzb8yG2NwJ) are a couple.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks.